# LDAP configuration for slapd-sock / slapo-sock / back-sock

Tags: openldap, slapd

Current system: CentOS 7.9, OpenLDAP 2.4

I would like to implement a "hook" into my LDAP operations so that when an ldapadd or ldapmodify operation takes place, a script is run *in addition to* the normal database operations. From my web searches, it appears that LDAP has a "socket overlay" mechanism that I've seen referred to as `slapd-sock`, `slapo-sock`, and `back-sock`. (Are all these the same thing, or have I missed an important difference?)

Here's a sample configuration from an [old thread question](https://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/201703/msg00036.html) of lines that are intended to be added to `slapd.conf`:

```
overlay sock
extensions binddn peername ssf connid
socketpath sockoverlay-listener
sockops modify add
```

All of the examples and man pages I've found so far show configuration lines to be added to `slapd.conf`. However, I've also seen that `slapd.conf` is on its way out as a means of controlling LDAP. I'd like to set something up with some stability, especially since I know I'll be upgrading to AlmaLinux 9.1 and OpenLDAP 2.6 before the end of the year.

My question is: How do I specify the above options within an LDIF file? Note that I'm not asking how to use the `ldapmodify` command. I'm asking how, from the above `slapd.conf` configuration, do I derive the appropriate cn, objectClass, and attributes to put into the LDIF file to enable `back-sock` (or whatever it's called)?

I know this is possible, since the OpenLDAP release notes indicate fixes that have been to controlling socket overlays from `cn=config`, but I can't find any examples of how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question, or rather, I found out how to find out the answer to my question.

The key to learning the LDAP cn=config cn, objectClass, and attributes for any given slapd.conf configuration is to create a dummy `slapd.conf` file, then use `slaptest`.

In my case, I created a `slap-mod.conf`:

```
include         /etc/openldap/schema/core.schema
database  hdb
suffix "dc=myoffice,dc=mycompany,dc=org"
rootdn "cn=Manager,dc=myoffice,dc=mycompany,dc=org"

modulepath /usr/lib64/openldap
moduleload back_sock.la

overlay sock
extensions binddn peername ssf connid
socketpath sockoverlay-listener
sockops modify add
```

I need to have just enough of a database definition for slaptest not to complain.

Then I ran

```
mkdir -p /tmp/slapd
slaptest -u -f slapd-mod.conf -F /tmp/slapd
```

When I looked at the `/tmp/slapd/cn=config/` directory, I saw the statements I needed. I haven't tried it yet, but it appears I need two LDIF files, After stripping out the usual {0} from slaptest, and adding a couple of tweaks to the dn:

```
dn: cn=module,cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module
olcModulePath: /usr/lib64/openldap
olcModuleLoad: back_sock.la
```

```
dn: olcOverlay=sock,olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcOverlayConfig
objectClass: olcOvSocketConfig
olcOverlay: sock
olcDbSocketPath: sockoverlay-listener
olcDbSocketExtensions: binddn
olcDbSocketExtensions: peername
olcDbSocketExtensions: ssf
olcDbSocketExtensions: connid
olcOvSocketOps: modify
olcOvSocketOps: add
```

*Edit*

After I figured it out and tried the above, I wound up "bricking" my LDAP server: it would no longer accept modify commands. Obviously this had to do with my not actually providing a backend script yet.

However, it turns out that while it's easy to add a line like `dn: olcOverlay=sock,olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config`, I couldn't delete it; whether this was due to the `back-sock` configuration or something else I can't say. I had to restore the entire LDAP configuration and database from backup.

Lesson learned: Just because you *can* do something via `cn=config` doesn't mean you *should* do something via `cn=config`. I would have been better off sticking to `slapd.conf` (assuming that file still works in CentOS7/OpenLDAP2.4) so configuration changes would be easy to back out.

How this will work when `slapd.conf` is finally, completely obsoleted is anyone's guess.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. You can also find the relevant schemas in the source for the specific backend, e.g., [here](https://git.openldap.org/openldap/openldap/-/blob/master/servers/slapd/back-sock/config.c#L46) for `back-sock`.